# Keep Process Spawned by Service Alive on Service Stop/Restart

Tags: systemd

I know this question has been asked a lot, but the answers so far are unsatisfactory. I've been struggling to find a good resolution for the past few workdays, and I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

**Scenario:**

- I have a webserver started as a system service on Ubuntu 22.04.
- The webserver runs as a non-privileged application user.
- The webserver needs to be able to kick off a script.
- The script will run pg_restore.
- The script needs to be able to stop the webserver service from connecting to postgres while pg_restore runs.
- Currently, when the script stops the webserver service (parent), the script (child) also dies. It doesn't matter if the script is spawned as a detached process or run with nohup and backgrounded. When the parent service is stopped or restarted, the script dies immediately.

**Possible Solution 1:** Disable connections in postgres for the application user.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185266/postgresql-temporarily-disable-connections

Problem: The script still needs to restart the web application service once connectivity is restored, which kills the script.

**Possible Solution 2:** Create a new service solely to run the script.

Reference: [What is the "correct" way to run a systemd service which spawns long running detached processes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/750669/what-is-the-correct-way-to-run-a-systemd-service-which-spawns-long-running-det)

Problem: It seems kludgy to create a system service that does nothing 99.9% of the time, only existing to run a script once. The script won't have root privs, so creating the service on-demand probably isn't an option without some sudo gymnastics, unless I've missed something.

**Possible Solution 3:** Set the webserver service KillMode to "process".

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32208782/cant-detach-child-process-when-main-process-is-started-from-systemd

Problem: Any processes spawned by the webserver during normal operation may not be properly managed (killed) by systemd on service restart. This could make it difficult to recover system resources in the event of a runaway process(s).

**Possible Solution 4:** Create a transient Process Control Group ala systemd-run.

Reference: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/resource_management_guide/chap-using_control_groups#sec-Creating_Transient_Cgroups_with_systemd-run

Problem: I'm trying to run `systemd-run --user --scope whoami > /home/appuser/test.txt 2>&1` from within the webservice (not from my shell) and receiving the following error message:
`Failed to connect to bus: $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS and $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not defined (consider using --machine=<user>@.host --user to connect to bus of other user)`. After searching and searching, I've tried the following:

- Set the env var with `export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS='unix:path=/run/user/$UID/bus'`. I then receive the error: `Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory`. Folks talk about running in a "normal login/shell" to resolve, but this is a webservice, not a normal user.
- The general recommendation is to avoid using 'sudo' and 'su'. I'm not using either.
- The `dbus` and `dbus-user-session` packages are installed.

Thank you for any assistance. This is driving me crazy!

Comment: Use `systemd-run -M user@`, don't manually twiddle `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`. Your command doesn't work because you've used single quotes, so the UID is never expanded.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Chris. This is the command I'm running: `systemd-run -M appuser@ whoami > /home/appuser/test.txt 2>&1`. It's now producing the authentication required error: `Failed to start transient service unit: Interactive authentication required.` Any suggestions?

Comment: We were able to get it run using sudo with: `sudo systemd-run --pty runuser -u APPUSER -- [rest_of_the_command]`. Would prefer to avoid the privilege escalation, though.